# A locally constant sheaf on a contractible space is constant.

Tags: general-topology, sheaf-theory

This is Exercise II.4. in the book [Sheaves on manifolds, Kashiwara and Schapira].

If X is simply connected and locally path connected, it is known that every locally constant sheaf F on X is constant.

Now X is contractible (thus simply-connected and path connected of course, but not necessarily locally path connected). How to prove that a locally constant sheaf F on X is still constant?

Comment: If $X$ is contractible, then it's path connected as well.

Comment: Yes. But it may not be locally path connected.

Comment: What makes you think that a path connected space is not necessarily locally path connected? It is.

Comment: In fact, the following set is path connected, but not locally path connected:  
X={(x, y) | x is rational or y=0}.

Comment: Nice example. But, if $X$ is path connected, then every point must have a path connected neighborhood, namely $X$ itself.

Comment: @Berci True, that is why a locally (path) connected space is defined by having a (path) connected neighbourhood basis for every point (see eg [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_connected_space))